# Have tabs in a row in Python Flet

Tags: python, flutter, user-interface, tabs, flet

## The issue

I am using [Flet](https://flet.dev/docs) as the GUI library for my project. I am trying to create a page where its separated in two half (left and right), where on the left side, there are some content, and on the right side there are tabs and more content in the tabs. (see image below)

[image: the UI I am aiming for]

The issue is that the UI breaks and is unresponsive when I try to add `ft.Tabs` under the `ft.Row`.

The question is whether it's a bug or intended. If it's intended, what can I do so I can build a UI where the tab section takes just half of the window (right side)? Should I use something else other than `ft.Row` to do so?

## Code to replicate the issue

```py
MAIN_GUI = ft.Container(
    margin=ft.margin.only(bottom=40),
    content=ft.Row([
        ft.Card(
            elevation=30,
            content=ft.Container(
                content=ft.Text("Amazing LEFT SIDE Content Here", size=50, weight=ft.FontWeight.BOLD),
                border_radius=ft.border_radius.all(20),
                bgcolor=ft.colors.WHITE24,
                padding=45,
            )
        ),
        ft.Tabs(
            selected_index=1,
            animation_duration=300,
            tabs=[
                ft.Tab(
                    text="Tab 1",
                    icon=ft.icons.SEARCH,
                    content=ft.Container(
                        content=ft.Card(
                            elevation=30,
                            content=ft.Container(
                                content=ft.Text("Amazing TAB 1 content", size=50, weight=ft.FontWeight.BOLD),
                                border_radius=ft.border_radius.all(20),
                                bgcolor=ft.colors.WHITE24,
                                padding=45,
                            )
                        )
                    ),
                ),
                ft.Tab(
                    text="Tab 2",
                    icon=ft.icons.SETTINGS,
                    content=ft.Text("Amazing TAB 2 content"),
                ),
            ],
        )
    ])
)


def main(page: ft.Page):
    page.padding = 50
    page.add(MAIN_GUI)
    page.update()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ft.app(target=main)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

As mentioned, what I am trying to do is to have the window separated to the left half and the right half, where the tabs would only be on the right half.

However, when running that code, only the tabs are visible on the right side and nothing is interactable.

Comment: Please add the code of your attempt to the question.

Comment: @СергейКох Sorry, forgot to do that. I have added a runnable Python code to replicate my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent blocks from colliding with each other, you just need to apply the [expand](https://flet.dev/docs/controls/row#expanding-children) property. For the main container, set it to True so that it occupies the entire available area, and for two tabs, set the necessary coefficients. I put 4 and 3.

```
import flet as ft

MAIN_GUI = ft.Container(
    margin=ft.margin.only(bottom=40),
    expand=True,
    content=ft.Row([
        ft.Card(
            elevation=30,
            expand=4,
            content=ft.Container(
                content=ft.Text("Amazing LEFT SIDE Content Here", size=50, weight=ft.FontWeight.BOLD),
                border_radius=ft.border_radius.all(20),
                bgcolor=ft.colors.WHITE24,
                padding=45,
            )
        ),
        ft.Tabs(
            selected_index=0,
            animation_duration=300,
            expand=3,
            tabs=[
                ft.Tab(
                    text="Tab 1",
                    icon=ft.icons.SEARCH,
                    content=ft.Container(
                        content=ft.Card(
                            elevation=30,
                            content=ft.Container(
                                content=ft.Text("Amazing TAB 1 content", size=50, weight=ft.FontWeight.BOLD),
                                border_radius=ft.border_radius.all(20),
                                bgcolor=ft.colors.WHITE24,
                                padding=45,
                            )
                        )
                    ),
                ),
                ft.Tab(
                    text="Tab 2",
                    icon=ft.icons.SETTINGS,
                    content=ft.Text("Amazing TAB 2 content"),
                ),
            ],
        )
    ])
)


def main(page: ft.Page):
    page.padding = 50
    page.add(MAIN_GUI)
    page.update()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ft.app(target=main)
    # cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That does solve the issue. I do have another side question though:
In the LEFT card, if the content wasn't `ft.Text` but `ft.Column` (with text in them), how can I prevent it from expanding? (https://pastebin.com/hKnJifFS)

Comment: Try to solve the problem yourself. If that doesn't work, ask a new question.